# How can we show that this sequence of characteristic converges?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, convolution, levy-processes

Let $E$ be a normed $\mathbb R$-vector space, $\mu$ be a probability measure on $\mathcal B(E)$ and $\varphi_\mu$ denote the characteristic function of $\mu$.

Assume $\mu$ is *infinitely divisible*, i.e. there is a sequence $(\mu_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ of probability measures on $\mathcal B(E)$ such that$^1$ $$\mu=\mu_n^{\ast n}\tag1$$ and hence $$\varphi_\mu=\varphi_{\mu_n}^n\tag2$$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$. We can easily show that$^2$ $$\left|\varphi_\mu\right|^{\frac2n}=\left|\varphi_{\mu_n}\right|^2=\varphi_{|\mu_n|^2}\;\;\;\text{for all }n\in\mathbb N.\tag3$$

> How can we show that $$\varphi(x'):=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\varphi_{\mu_n}\right|^2=\left.\begin{cases}1&\text{, if }\varphi_\mu(x')\ne0\\0&\text{, otherwise}\end{cases}\right\}\tag4$$ for all $x'\in E'$?

Note that the claim is made (in the case $E=\mathbb R^d$, $d\in\mathbb N$) in the proof of Lemma 7.5 in Sato's book *Lévy Processes and Infinitely Divisible Distributions*.

> *Remark*: If you can provide an answer for the case $E=\mathbb R^d$, $d\in\mathbb N$, I would be interested in it as well.

---

$^1$ If $\nu_1,\ldots,\nu_k$ are measures on $\mathcal B(E)$ and $$\theta_k:E^k\to E\;,\;\;\;x\mapsto x_1+\cdots+x_k,$$ then the *convolution* of $\nu_1,\ldots,\nu_k$ is defined to be the pushforward measure $$\nu_1\ast\cdots\ast\nu_k:=\theta_k(\nu_1\otimes\cdots\otimes\nu_k)$$ of the product measure $\nu_1\otimes\cdots\otimes\nu_k$ with respect to $\theta_k$. If $\nu_1=\cdots=\nu_k$, we simply write $\nu_1^{\ast k}:=\nu_1\ast\cdots\ast\nu_k$.

$^2$ If $\nu$ is a finite measure on $\mathcal B(E)$, then $$\nu^-(B):=\nu(-B)\;\;\;\text{for }B\in\mathcal B(E)$$ and $$|\nu|^2:=\nu\ast\nu^-.$$

Comment: Say $z\in\Bbb C$. If $|z|=1$ and $z\ge0$ then $z^n=z=1$. If $|z|<1$ then $z^n\to0$.

Comment: @OliverDiaz The characteristic function is defined by $$\varphi_\mu(x'):=\int\mu({\rm d}x)e^{{\rm i}\langle x,\:x'\rangle}\;\;\;\text{for }x'\in E'.$$ Measures on Banach spaces naturally occur, for example, in the theory of SPDEs.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Well, yes, but why does that imply the claim? I need to say that I meanwhile think that the second equality in $(3)$ is not important for this question. I think the really important point is the first equality and I guess your intention is to take $z=\varphi_\mu(x')$, for some fixed $x'\in E'$. However, while we've clearly got $|\varphi_\mu(x')|\le1$, I don't see why $z=\varphi(x')\ne0$ should imply $|z|=1$ and $z\ge0$.

Comment: @OliverDiaz I'm not sure whether we really need additional assumptions. Do you know how we can prove the claim for $E=\mathbb R^d$? If I would know why the claim holds in this case, we could check whether the argument breaks for general $E$.

Comment: @0xbadf00d: If $\phi_\mu(x')\neq0$, then $0< |\phi_{\mu_n}(x')|^2=|\phi_{\mu}(x')|^{2/n}\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}1$ by the elementary fact that $\sqrt[n]{a}\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}1$ for any $a\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$.

Comment: @OliverDiaz Thank you. I was confused by the way the argument was made in Sato's book. The main ingredient is obviously Lévy's continuity theorem. I think we can use the Itō-Nisio theorem for the general case. But on the one hand, I'm not sure how exactly and, on the other hand, my actual goal is to show that $\varphi_\mu$ has no zeros and there might be a better approach to show this.  As you suggested, I've [asked for this on MO](https://mathoverflow.net/q/395537/91890).

Comment: never mind, sorry...